# How to properly add repository of different release?

Tags: 16.04, updates

Provided Ubuntu 16.04 installed I want to add artful (17.10) repository to be able to install additional packages.

Simply doing this seems to be not enough as there also seem 'artful-updates' and 'artful-security' repos available:

```
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y -u 'artful'
```

Does this mean if I do not install these additional repos I may end up with non-secure package installed?

Should I install everything instead like this?:

```
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y -u 'artful'
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y -u 'artful-security'
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y -u 'artful-updates'
```

Comment: What packages are you looking for, that you are trying to get from the artful release repositories?

Comment: Well, there might be newer packages needed e.g. bcmwl-kernel-source but here I'm interested in a general idea of how release repos are organized.

Comment: Generally it is not a good idea to mix repos unless you are very experienced in package management and debugging problems. IMO you should consider upgrading. If you must mix and match use pinning - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto and install only those packages that are essential.

Answer (score 4):

Ah.  Generally speaking it's not a good idea to pull packages from releases other than the one that you are operating - they have been compiled for the kernels included in the release, and to work with the newer versions of other packages and libraries.

I *believe* that if you were to simply add all of the Artful repositories in the manner you are suggesting, that you system would attempt to do something looking very much like a full distribution upgrade, as almost every package that you have in 16.04 has a newer version in 17.10.  Upgrading in this manner would be interesting to watch, but probably doomed for failure.

If you are looking for a specific package, please try to examine [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/) - most of the release package files are there, and often in newer versions packaged for your release.

Comment: @panther your comment and my answer seem aligned...

Comment: Probably best to try, in order upgrading ubuntu, backports, ppa, and compile from source all preferable to adding a repository and pinning.

Comment: I think "not a good idea" understates the risk.  Consider including the terms "*very bad idea*", "*unskilled users may break their system quite horribly*", "*backup your data*",  and "*path heading toward a re-install*" and then the obligatory "If you want new software, than perhaps LTS is the wrong choice for you"

Comment: @user535733 I understand, but am quickly becoming a master of understatement!  My own limited skill comes primarily from doing stupid things, and then discovering why they are stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing software sources from different releases is likely to result in an unworkable system. It only takes 1 updated library that is not compatible to trigger a chain of nasty package management errors.